# openURL Callback?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, segue

User refuses location, I send user to Location settings on Settings app:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:"prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES")!)
```

User authorizes location from Settings app, returns to my app with `Back to App` on top left

How do I know that he came back to the app? `viewDidAppear` doesn't work

Comment: what happened   ?...

Comment: you found any solution for this?, you can answer this question

Answer (score 4):

You can **easily detect** by checking `AppDelegate's` method:-

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication!) {
```

Or by **registering a notification in your view controller's viewDidLoad()** by `NSNotificationCenter`:-

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "applicationWillEnterForeground", name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)


//calling selector method
 func applicationWillEnterForeground() {
            println("did enter foreground")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`UIApplicationDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidBecomeActive:).

Answer (score 0):

Use NSNotificationCenter in your viewController

Call this on viewDidLoad

```
- (void)registerAppEnterForeground
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(applicationWillEnterForeground)
     name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
     object:nil];
}


-(void)applicationWillEnterForeground
{
 /*HANDLE YOUR CODE HERE*/
}
```