# applicationWillEnterForeground not getting called

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I want to detect when the user comes back to the app after calling a certain number:

```
  let scheme = "tel://+1234567890"
    if let url = URL(string: scheme) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:],
                                  completionHandler: {
                                    (success) in

        })
    }
```

As suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35546515/848377) answer, I am trying to detect when the app enters the foreground by using:

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication!) {}
```

But the problem is that the above function never gets called.

Here is my `info.plist` file:

[image]

Comment: Use this method applicationDidBecomeActive

Comment: did you tried applicationDidBecomeActive(_:)?